# How to create a historical timeline using Pandas Dataframe and matplotlib

Tags: python, time-series, pandas, matplotlib

So I've seen a few answers on here that helped a bit, but my dataset is larger than the ones that have been answered previously. To give a sense of what I'm working with, [here's a link to the full dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Fdg_OywL05MYHwoCEcytEuw9i5Lba9gYsvBEFLO4l8/). I imported this into a jupyter notebook using pandas. I've included a picture of one attempted solution, which was found at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937397/how-to-sort-a-historical-timeline-written-with-python-matplotlib), right here:
[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cjB6.png). The issue is that 1. This is difficult to read and 2. I don't know how to flatten it out so that it looks like a traditional timeline. The issue becomes more apparent when I try and work with larger segments, such as this one: [It's basically unreadable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3rXs.png) Here's the code I used to produce both of these (I just modified the included code in order to change which section of the overall dataset was used).

```
event = Xia['EnglishName']
begin = Xia['Start']
end = Xia['Finish']
length = Xia['Length']

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.barh(range(len(begin)), (end-begin), .3, left=begin)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=15)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=20)
plt.title('Xia Dynasty', fontsize = '25')
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize = '20')
plt.yticks(range(len(begin)), "")
plt.xlim(-2250, -1750)
plt.ylim(-1,18)
for i in range(18):
    plt.text(begin.iloc[i] + length.iloc[i]/2, i+.25, event.iloc[i], ha='center', fontsize = '12')
```

This code semi-works, but I'd prefer if the bars were either closer together or differently colored and all on the same y-value. I appreciate any and all help. I've been trying to figure this out for about two weeks now and am hitting a brick wall.

Comment: Is there a chance that two bars overlap. If yes, how do you manage to have a flat y value.

Comment: They do overlap sometimes (at one particular value, e.g. ruler 1 ends at year 50 and ruler 2 begins at year 50) but I would be more than happy to just massage the data to make it begin + x and end - x (where x is a very small value).

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the late reply. I don't know whether the below kind of plot suffices for what you are looking. [image: plot]

If yes is the case, you might like [`matplotlib.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hlines.html). I am providing a sample code for generating a picture like the above.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

for x in range(0, 10, 2):
    color = random.choice(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'])
    plt.hlines(1, x, x + 2, colors=color, lw=5)
    plt.text(x + 1, 1.01, color, ha='center')
plt.show()
```

Let me know if this was helpful!